# How to make android app which have multiple business type?

Tags: android

I want make android application for multiple business type. If i select one business then the flow of application flows as per selected business type. Or i configure the app as per business type. Is this possible, I know it will be done using if....else but i don't wan't use this.

Comment: This is way too broad and unclear. Please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question please. This community isn't a free tutor service where people would sit down with you for hours to A) figure what exactly you want to do and B) to then design a vision with you how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Figure out all common screens and Activities, classes etc and make a package for them. You have to make sure what is "similar" and what is "same". Only "same" things should go here.

Then Figure out how many business types there could be? Are they static? If yes then make separate Activities for each of them.Craft a full fledged program control for each business type. Ideally each type is totally isolated from other. There might be a code duplication, but that would be "similar" code, not "same" so no problem.

Now when application starts, determine business type, call respective activity and your are good to go.